# Comparison always fails with char and constant

Tags: c, if-statement, char

I am trying to compare the first character of a string and a hex constant to determine the type of data. But every time it fails. Can anyone explain why below comparison always fails.

```
char charray[] = {0xAA, 0x00, 0x02};
char ch = charray[0];
if (0xAA == ch)
{
    printf("Equal\n");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
char charray[] = {0xAA, 0x00, 0x02};
```

The char type has implementation-defined signedness, meaning that on some systems it will be equivalent to `signed char`. A `signed char` can only store values up to 0x7F and the MSB will get treated as a sign bit. This is what happens in your case, `0xAA` gets converted to a signed value of `-86` (it is implementation-defined what value it gets, I'm assuming two's complement).

The sign is then preserved in the expression `0xAA == ch`, because `ch` is then promoted to type `int` and the sign is preserved. Meaning that you'll actually be comparing `0xAA == -86` which is false.

To avoid bugs like this, always use `uint8_t` when doing any form of arithmetic on byte level.

Answer (score 1):

`0xAA` is an `int` literal. `char` could be either signed or unsigned on your system. The C standard allows either.

In `0xAA == ch`, the `ch` is promoted to an `int` type, and the comparison evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (0xAA == ch)
```

Assuming `char` is `signed char` (the behavior of `char` as  `signed char` or `unsigned char` is implementation dependent in C), `char` is promoted to `int` in the `==` expression and in a 32-bit system you are actually comparing:

```
if (0xAA == 0xFFFFFFAA)
```

which is false.

One way to prevent the sign-extension is to cast the right operand to `unsigned char`:

```
if (0xAA == (unsigned char) ch)
```

But the best is simply to use `unsigned char` when you declare your array.

Comment: No, he is actually comparing `0xAA == -86`. Not necessarily the same thing as `0xAA == 0xFFFFFFAA`, depending on how the implicit promotions turn out on the specific system.

Comment: @Lundin if you want to be picky, he is actually comparing `0xAA == (signed char) 0xAA` which is even different as the conversion is implementation defined.

Comment: My point is: as long as the left operand (the int literal) is an `int`, then the char will only go through integer promotion (the integer promotion rule) and remain signed. But if the literal was an unsigned type, there would also be balancing (usual arithmetic conversions) and the right operand would get converted to unsigned type too. In which case you would actually end up with it being equal to `0xFFFFFFAAu`. But that doesn't happen in this specific example.

Comment: @Lundin if the left operand was `unsigned int`, then `ch` would still be promoted to `int` before the final conversion to `unsigned int`.